# VBA Application defined or object-defied error 1004 for my .csv extracton data code

Tags: excel, vba, csv

I'm trying to have a code that will get the table data from a .csv file and transfer it in a proper way to my Master working file, named "Meterd Monthly Data Colector". Basicaly to open.csv with Power Query function, process the data inside, and save it/paste it in my Master working file Inside this file i have e Sheet named "Input" in which i want the .csv data to be saved, when processed. But i have an issue with my code - i received the above mentioned Run-time error 1004 (so something is unknown i suppose) in `.ListObject.DisplayName = "TSO Metered Data"`. But i can't quite get it what to do and to define the sheet named "TSO Metered Data" from the source file with the same name ( source file name "TSO Metered Data"; single sheet inside, named "TSO Metered Data").
Here is my code :

```
Sub PowerQueryTransform()

  Dim myWorkBook As Excel.Workbook
  Dim myWorkSheet As Excel.Worksheet

  Set myWorkBook = Application.Workbooks("Meterd Monthly Data Colector.xlsm")
  Set myWorkSheet = myWorkBook.Sheets("Input")
  myWorkSheet.Select

  ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
  With ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(SourceType:=0, Source:= _
    "OLEDB;Provider=Microsoft.Mashup.OleDb.1;Data Source=$Workbook$;Location=TSO Metered    Data;Extended Properties=""""" _
    , Destination:=Range("$A$1")).QueryTable
    .CommandType = xlCmdSql
    .CommandText = Array( _
    "SELECT * FROM [TSO Metered Data]")
    .RowNumbers = False
    .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
    .PreserveFormatting = True
    .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
    .BackgroundQuery = True
    .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
    .SavePassword = False
    .SaveData = True
    .AdjustColumnWidth = True
    .RefreshPeriod = 0
    .PreserveColumnInfo = True
    .ListObject.DisplayName = "TSO Metered Data"
    .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
 End With
 Range("A1").Select
 Windows("Meterd Monthly Data Colector.xlsm").Activate

End Sub
```

Comment: I would guess the statement should be `.DisplayName = "TSO Metered Data"` (without `.ListObject`) because the `With`-clause is related to the Listobject you just created.

Comment: Now it's Error 438 Object doesn't support this property or method.